# Work around to create collection within transaction in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I have REST apis that creates mongoDB collection at runtime and keeps the collection name in another collection.

MongoDB now supports transaction and does allow only CRUD operations within a transaction not create collection operation.

Im thinking that to keep all the collection names within a transaction in request context and create the collections once transaction is completed. Is there any other way or workaround to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Mongo 4.4, you can create collections and indexes inside transactions. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-create-collections-indexes)